# Why wont i get any data to my codeigniter view?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I start with my questions:

1. Why do i not receive the data for the Rangers article in the view?
2. Why doesn't the path: http://igniter.se/index.php/news/view/Rangers work? I thought that was how it was supposed to work: Controller/method in model/Attributes?

I was following the second tutorial at ellislab.com [News_Section](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/news_section.html). I have seen others having some problems with this tutorial too, but i haven't found the same problem i'm having...

My issue is that i don't receive any data when navigating from all news to just one (on an href).

At this path will show all of the news in the db:

```
http://ignitertut.se/index.php/news/
```

At these paths (for example) i will get a 404:

```
http://ignitertut.se/index.php/news/view/, http://ignitertut.se/index.php/news/view/Rangers/
```

But at this path i will get an empty page: No data, No header&footer templates included, and No titel in the head which usually gets one automatically.

```
http://ignitertut.se/index.php/news/Ragers/
```

Where Rangers is a slug for an article about Rangers, stored in the DB.

**The Model:**

```
<?php
class News_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        //Preloaded db
    }

    public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
    {
        if ($slug === FALSE)
        {
            $query = $this->db->get('news');
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

**The View with all the articles - "index.php"**

```
<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>

            <h2><?php echo $news_item['title'] ?></h2>
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $news_item['text'] ?>
            </div>
            <p><a href="news/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">View article</a></p>

        <?php endforeach ?>
```

**The View for the specific article - "view.php"**

```
<?php
echo '<h2>'.$news_item['title'].'</h2>';
echo '<p>' .$news_item['text']. '</p>';
```

**The Controller**

```
class News extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('news_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
        $data['title'] = 'News archive';

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function view($slug)
    {
        $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);

        if (empty($data['news_item']))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

I've auto loaded the database and set:
`$config['base_url']    = 'http://ignitertut.se/';` (Running locally)

Comment: are u getting the slug values ?

Comment: Seems alright, what happens if you set the base_url to `''`?

Answer (score 0):

The word you are calling as slug is url parameter  . In codeigniter there is a way to get the url parameter.

Inorder to work you existing code change the controller function for view to this

```
public function view()
    {
        $slug = $this->uri->segment(2);
        $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);

        if (empty($data['news_item']))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

Refer this url for more details
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: I have updated my question with the code for the view which displays all articles and where you can click on one for getting to a page about just that article. Adding your $slug = $this->... did nothing for now.

Comment: could you debug and see whether you are getting slug value on the view function . $slug = $this->uri->segment(3);

Comment: Got an error: Undefined index: title, when adding `$slug = $this->uri->segment(3)`. That is not the case for `$slug = $this->uri->segment(2)`.

Comment: what is the url you called?

Comment: ha man what are you doing . Do you have a function called Rangers ? r u new to codeigniter?

Comment: "I was following the second tutorial at ellislab.com News_Section..." - I'm a season Pro, what do you think?

Comment: "Why do i not receive the data for the Rangers article in the view?" - i think so.